# Is there a Safari Extension that automatically tracks my daily time usage on Safari?

Tags: windows, safari, safari-extensions

I am looking for an extension in Safari that automatically tracks my time in Safari.  Specifically, I want:
1)  When I start Safari, the timer automatically starts/resumes.
2)  When I stop Safari, the timer pauses.
3)  The timer would reset every day or at a frequency I specify.

The basic idea is that I can track my daily usage on the internet at work, so that I don't spend too much time goofing off.

I don't think there's anything in the official Safari Extensions gallery.  There is WebWatch and My Work&Time, but the former doesn't satisfy criteria 2 and My Work&Time is not automatic.

I'm running Safari 5.0.5 on Windows XP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its not a Safari specific solutions, but Slife works pretty well to do what you're saying.

http://www.slifeweb.com/

Not only will it monitor how much time you spend on Safari, but also on everything else.  So now you can get an entire picture of what you do during the day.

Comment: Thanks. To be honest, I haven't tried this yet, but it seems like the best solution.  I started using the Opera Browser.